# Is there a way to have multiple Block types in a Shopify section?

Tags: shopify, liquid

In a Shopify section I have an image picker block to make a gallery, and in the same section I have a url block to make any number of buttons.

The problem is both block types appear in the same 'Content' area of the theme editor. This makes it look quite confusing for an editor.

Is there a way to have 2 separate blocks areas, one for the image gallery and the other for buttons?

[image]

```
"blocks": [
  {
    "type": "button",
    "name": "Button",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "button_link",
        "label": "Button link"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "image",
    "name": "Image slide",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "image",
        "label": "Image"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you're trying to achieve. Add some screens on how you would like to make it look?

Comment: @Vladimir Added image for example

Comment: See my answer below. There is no way to split them and group by type within the same section but you can split buttons and images into 2 sections and include both on the template. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, at current there is no way to tell Shopify to display blocks in this way. All blocks can be arranged to be in any order, regardless of what the 'type' of each block is.  Whoever is administering the store would need to manually arrange the blocks into a sensible order.

If you want to make it easier to split up your block types during the *rendering* of the items, you can use something like this:

```
{% assign image_blocks = section.blocks | where: 'type', 'image' %}
{% for block in image_blocks %}
  <!-- Stuff -->
{% endfor %}

{% assign button_blocks = section.blocks | where: 'type', 'button' %}
{% for block in button_blocks %}
  <!-- Stuff -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 different sections and include both .e.g:

```
{% section 'buttons' %}

{% section 'images' %}
```

Where:

**sections/buttons.liquid**

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Buttons",
    "class": "buttons-section",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "button",
        "name": "Button",
        "settings": [
          {
            "type": "URL",
            "id": "button_link",
            "label": "Button link"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

**sections/images.liquid**

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Images",
    "class": "images-section",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "image",
        "name": "Image slide",
        "settings": [
          {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "image",
            "label": "Image"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

So you'll get this:

[image: Two sections included example]

Comment: Unfortunately, I needed them in the same section for layout reasons. I wish the 'Rich' text field allowed link classes.

Comment: What do you mean for layout reasons? You still can have both sections on the same layout/page. It just splits sections in the admin panel theme settings, that what you asked for based on the screenshot added to the question i.e. you wanted to split them in there, did I miss something?

Comment: I just mean that it needs to be styled in a way that requires both elements to be in one section.